# No network devices available on XPS 13 developer edition (no wifi)

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-netbook, xps

I just bought the XPS 13 developer edition (14.04). It worked perfectly, wifi was good etc. But after turning on my device this Monday my computer wasn't able to make a connection anymore with a wifi device. In the top bar "no network devices available" is displayed while "enable networking" is checked.
I know it's a common problem, but the solutions given for related questions never work out for me, since my connection is totally gone. How am I able to update drivers etc without internet? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
jeroen@jeroen-XPS-13-9350:~$ dkms status
btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260, 1.7, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260, 1.7, 3.19.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed
intel-hid, 2.0, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
intel-hid, 2.0, 3.19.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid, 0.201512022217~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid, 0.201512022217~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.19.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rts-cr, 1.4.3oem2, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rts-cr, 1.4.3oem2, 3.19.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed
synaptic-i2c-hid-3.13.0-32-backport, 1.6.4: added
```

[image]

Comment: Have you already tried `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`, especially if you didn't but but woke it up from hibernation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is a link in my question with the results of the commands. @Pilot6

Comment: Next time please post text from terminal, not a screenshot. I do not know what is that "developer edition". If it is Ubuntu 14.04, then you have an old kernel that does not support this adapter. It can be fixed by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial`.

Comment: And probably you installed a driver for it. Please post output of `dkms status` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 The developer edition is an XPS with ubuntu 14.04 installed. 
Are you sure I can install something without any internet connectivity?

Comment: You can disable Secure Boot in BIOS and get it back.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: I tried all those options, but nothing works. I get a lot of errors about a lack of connectivity. I can't download or install anything. 
I just decided to reboot from fabric setting. So far it seems I got wifi again. But now the question is: How can I prevent this from happening again?
I thank you a lot for your time and help! much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem after using Software Updater.  As Pilot6 mentioned, you can disable Secure Boot which will allow the updated modules to run.  You should understand the security implications of doing so.

Since this is a Dell, press F12 on boot, then select Other Options > BIOS Setup.  Secure Boot > Disable

Comment: Exactly! that was the solution. I should have updated this post back then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clear. You updated the kernel and now unsigned 3rd party kernel modules, like `btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260` can't load with Secure Boot enabled in BIOS.

The easiest solution is to disable it. In this case everything should work as before.

As I noted in comments, with new kernels you do not need 3rd party modules to use this wireless adapter. You can upgrade the kernel to 4.4.

But in this case you should remove ALL 3rd party dkms modules, and the system may need some manual setup.